# How to make only a method generic in a python class

Tags: python, python-3.6, mypy

I have the following base class to represent fields:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
    def validate(self, value: T):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

I also have an enum to represent the available implementations of this class:

```py
class Types(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()

    @staticmethod
    def from_instance(instance: BaseClass) -> "Types":
        if isinstance(instance, ClassA):
            return Types.A
        if isinstance(instance, ClassB):
            return Types.B
        raise ValueError("Not supported")
```

Now, from these class, I have several implementations:

```py
@dataclass
class ClassA(BaseClass[str]):
    def validate(self, value: str):
        pass


@dataclass
class ClassB(BaseClass[int]):
    def validate(self, value: int):
        pass
```

After this setup, I have another class to store a list of `BaseClass`:

```py
@dataclass
class Container:
    instances: List[BaseClass]

    def get_by_type(self, type: Types) -> List[BaseClass]:
        return [instance for instance in self.instances if type == Types.from_instance(instance)]
```

At the end I have the following code and the following error:

```py
def function(fields_from_class_a: List[ClassA]):
    print(fields_from_class_a)


container = Container(instances=[ClassA(), ClassB()])
fields = container.get_by_type(Types.A)


# throws error:
#  Argument 1 to "function" has incompatible type "List[BaseClass[Any]]"; expected "List[ClassA]"
function(fields)
```

So my question is, can I modify the code in such a way that the method `get_by_type` is correctly typed?

Comment: Not that it's crucial here, but `function` accepting a `list[something]` should often use `Sequence` or even less restrictive container type instead to avoid variance issues (if you don't modify the list, allow `Sequence`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassA` is only mapped at runtime to `Types.A` in `Types.from_instance()`.

You would have to use `BaseClass[Literal[Types.A]]` instead of `ClassA`:

```py
# def function(fields_from_class_a: List[ClassA]):                     # Change this
def function(fields_from_class_a: List[BaseClass[Literal[Types.A]]]):  # to this
```

And type `Container.get_by_type()` as such:

```py
TypesT = TypeVar("TypesT", Literal[Types.A], Literal[Types.B])   # Add this

# def get_by_type(self, type: Types) -> List[BaseClass]:         # Change this
def get_by_type(self, type: TypesT) -> List[BaseClass[TypesT]]:  # to this
```

Comment: I cannot use Literal, the python version is 3.6 (see quesion tags)

Comment: Try `pip install typing_extensions` and then `from typing_extensions import Literal`?